# RequireUniqueEmail = false not working MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a MVC 5 solution where I can manage "Organizations" and users can register under them. I implemented the account controller to get the Organization ID from the register form and save it inside the AspNetUsers table. Now I know which user belongs to which organization.

But now I have a problem, each time I try to register an user using the same email registered to another organization I get the message: "Name t@t.com is already taken."

Do you know how to make ASP.NET Membership to allow duplicate emails?

I tried to use this code below inside my Account Controller but it did not work for me:

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
{
    RequireUniqueEmail = false
};
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Any ideas? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: any solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable `RequiresUniqueEmail` in your provider (via `web.config settings`) Like numerous options can be enabled/disabled

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="SimpleConnection" applicationName="abc" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you're using email as the username rather than having a separate username field. Hence `Name t@t.com is already taken` - it's treating `t@t.com` as a username. Create a unique UserName.