# Allowing RequireUniqueEmail = false gives error in ChangePasswordAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my c# code, I have allowed accepting the users with the same emails with the below code.

```
UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = false
    };
```

This works absolutely fine, however, when the user goes ahead and changes his password it gives him an error saying, "The email 'zyz@domain.com' is already taken". If he is not sharing his email with other users, then the functionality works fine. Below is the code to change the password of the user.

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword,
                model.NewPassword);
```

Where should I make the change now, so this works??

Answer (score 0):

Are you treating the email address as a username? If you are, then give the users a unique username but allow the same email address.

Also check in your web.config for the RequiresUniqueEmail tag as well

```
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="SimpleConnection" applicationName="abc" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Also, view the following related threads (it benefits everyone if you search prior questions):

[AspNet Identity RequireUniqueEmail = false throws exception on CreateAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478593/aspnet-identity-requireuniqueemail-false-throws-exception-on-createasync)

[RequireUniqueEmail = false not working MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926574/requireuniqueemail-false-not-working-mvc-5)